Making typescript recognize index for subsequent parameter
I have a factory that returns a Query Object with structure like this:
query.ts
class Query<T> {
    private queryList: Record<string, string>

    async init(url: string, queries: Record<string, string>) {
        this.queryList = queries
    }
    execute(command: string extends keyof this.queryList, 
        parameter: Record<string, string>
    ): Promise<T[]> {
        
    }
}

export async function InitializeQuery<T>(
    url: string, 
    queries: Record<string, string>
) {
    const queryObject = new Query<T>();
    await queryObject.init(url, queries)
    return queryObject;
}

And a table definition as this:
table.d.ts
type ItemType = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    weight: number,
    createdBy: string
}

So I execute it like:
index.ts
import { InitializeQuery } from './query.js';

const itemNamedQueries: Record<string, string> = {
    "selectById": "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = :id",
    "selectByName": "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name = :name",
    "findAll": "SELECT * FROM Table"
}

const query = await InitializeQuery<ItemType>(
    'mysql://user:pass@localhost/database', 
    itemNamedQueries);
const result = await query.execute("selectById", {id: 25})

The code is currently works fine, but I found that I made typos here and there regarding itemNamedQuery names.
So, I want that if I run  execute(, and press ctrl+space, the IDE would recognize that command parameter from execute method are the keys of that namedQueries and give me a list of possible commands from the index.
How I can achieve that?
UPDATE:
I tried making this simple test in VSCode:
const test: Record<string, string> = {
    FindAll: "SELECT * FROM TableData",
    Find: "SELECT * FROM TableData WHERE id = :id",
} as const

function fn<C extends keyof typeof test>(command: C) {

}

fn()


and it didn't work.

Aside: do you need init method to be async? It would be preferable for new Query(url, queries) to do what InitializeQuery does. Or at least do the async part in InitializeQuery and pass the result to Query.constructor

Yes. I made init to load the database driver. I have another class to lazy import a driver, based on the url provided. I would make the url, database and table without async, but I can't lazy import without async.

When using namedQueries constant, you must not loose its precise type.
Currently, you do so by giving it explicit type Record<string, string>
After that, you can use generics to propagate that type across your functions.
const namedQueries = {
    "selectById": "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE id = :id",
    "selectByName": "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE name = :name",
    "findAll": "SELECT * FROM Table"
} as const satisfies Record<string, string>;

export async function InitializeQuery<QUERIES extends Record<string, string>>(url: string, queries: QUERIES) {
    const queryObject = new Query<QUERIES>();
    await queryObject.init(url, queries)
    return queryObject;
}

class Query<QUERIES extends Record<string, string>> {
    private queryList: QUERIES = null as any;


    async init(url: string, queries: QUERIES) {
        this.queryList = queries
    }
    execute(command: keyof QUERIES, parameter: Record<string, string>) {
        
    }
}

const query = await InitializeQuery('mysql://localhost', namedQueries);
const resultOk = await query.execute("selectById", {id: '25'})   //OK
const resultBad = await query.execute("selectById1", {id: '25'}) //Expected error

BTW it would make sense to also define accepted parameters in namedQueries and accept only those.

I see that you omit <> from the caller. I assume, typescript would recognize it automatically. But what if I want to add TableType there? Like: class Query<QUERIES extends Record<string, string>, TableType> {} and then pass the TableType to execute<TableType>(command: keyof QUERIES, parameter: Record<string, string>): Promise<TableType> {} How should I put the generics at InitializeQuery?

POC: https://tsplay.dev/NrBe2N

I have tried making a very simple function, and it didn't work. I've updated the question with a function to test.

Same problem as in initial example: you must not loose its precise type. Currently, you do so by giving it explicit type Record<string, string>: TS Playground

Ah.. I see.. Thank you. That solved it. Also that solved the other one, too.
